# android listen for app launch

Tags: android, launch, listen

I need to develop a service which listen for every activity start.
Must I do something like this?

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i < runningAppProcessInfo.size(); i++) {
    Log.v("Proc: ", runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName);
}
```

And do I need to do it every X seconds? Does it affect battery consumption?

Comment: Additional info: ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1) will return the first task from the list of running tasks. This task seems to always be the one in the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is currently no way to listen to an app's launch, Unless it is the first time that it is launching. 
[ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH) (Broadcast Action: Sent to the installer package of an application when that application is first launched (that is the first time it is moved out of the stopped state).

So I guess your solution is the best for this right now.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is a class `IActivityController.Stub` in `android.app` package.
But this is an `{@hide}` interface (as someone said there have some method to access `@hide` api).

We can set a Listener to listen Activity switch like this:

```
mAm = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault();          
    try {
        mAm.setActivityController(new ActivityController());

   } catch (RemoteException e) {
        System.err.println("** Failed talking with activity manager!");}
```

and Class   ActivityManagerNative  is @hide also.
ActivityController is a  class extends IActivityController.Stub .

How to access @hide Api:

1. you can get the android source code to build an have-@hide-api Android.jar to use.
2. by reflection.

Comment: A note about this: on modern versions of Android, calling `setActivityController` requires the `SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER` permission which requires that your application is signed with the key used to sign the Android framework, which isn't really possible if you're developing a third party application designed to run on all ROMs.