# How to know when another app is begin launching?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android:how does application Protector app works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838546/androidhow-does-application-protector-app-works)

How can i be notified when new app begin  launching? clearly to say, i click on app icon , and app begin launching, i want to set my service to  observer of that event (if there is any). Is there any event or some way to know that before app launched ?

Comment: at onCreate() method u can do coding and send the required info where u want, thats it according to me. :)

Comment: but , how can get into that method of app ? o.O

Comment: i have nothing, only listener to that event(if there is)

Comment: i really need to know get info about that, i make app-service about interrupting apps according to user, but there is no guide or code to inform when new app begins launching

Comment: There were some questions on SO, look for them.

Comment: @Mighter can you share any links ?

Comment: I'm afraid you're most likely going to have to parse the Log messages in real-time in order to do what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeRoy, my problem is that, i must show user like this : if any app added to blocklist(e.g) when that app clicked to launch, i must show that this app doesnt launch and toast information "this app has blocked". i may immediatly try to set that activity to waiting mode, and kill process from running processes. but i dont know exactly

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would get the [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) with a call to

```
getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)
```

and then setup my program with the following code:

```
private final static Handler updateHandler = new Handler();
private static long WAKEUP_INTERVAL = 10000;    // 10secs?

private Runnable periodicUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        checkRunningProcesses();
        updateHandler.postDelayed(this, WAKEUP_INTERVAL);
    }
};
```

to do periodical checks of the following two things:

1. check [getRecentTasks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29) to find out what user has launched recently (requres [GET_TASKS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_TASKS) permission)
2. get from [getRunningAppProcesses()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) and keep somewhere list of running processes just in case periodical check interval has been chosen too long and some processes were added/removed but did not show in getRecentTasks()

This way I could not get an instant notification about program launch, but could find about that soon enough (seconds later, maybe) to do something about it.

One more thing, it might be a wise idea to stop checks when screen goes dark, to save the battery.

Answer (score 0):

[android listen for app launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596488/android-listen-for-app-launch)

You can't really do this with intents or anything like that.  Check out this guy's brute hack.  Not a great solution but the closest you'll get.

Comment: after this ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH , that app continue launching or waiting for callback?

Comment: You're missing the answer.  The answer is creating a service with the code in the question portion of the link.  The ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH is not going to do anything for you.  Furthermore, this solution will quickly drain the battery of anyone using this app.  I'm sure it would be enough of a drain for people to consider uninstalling.

Comment: i think in this way.after my app-service installed on device, app require to reboot phone. and any app (except system apps) when begins launching (for 1st time) always ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH is called, and i check if that app is in blocklist or not, then if i can i abort that process i abort

Comment: If you aren't going to listen to people telling you the way to solve your problem then why are you on SO?  How do you expect your service to persist through reboot?

This is a bad idea.  You don't want to kill processes in android for a variety of reasons.  There is a reason there aren't any handles for you to program onto when another application launches...

Comment: it is bad. i listen people, but i believe that there must be solution of this problem. but it seems i must find other way

Comment: The OS is built a certain way for security purposes and I don't think you're going to be able to implement a solution for this besides a service that runs all the time and would be a huge battery drain.  I really don't think there's any programmatic handles in the OS for you to implement any other solutions.

Comment: i dont create it for global using. i am in competation. firstly i thinked i must confirm that there is ability to do it. again i must think new idea :/