# Running my application when another app is loaded

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, power-management

It's a litle bit hard to explain, but i'll try..

There is my app, lets call it appA and another app (that I DIDN'T create, which already exist), lets call it appB.
I want that the moment appB is loaded, appA will load too.

I know it's basically possible by setting a service with an interval of seconds, but it obviously will drain battery.

Or I could somehow make a BroadcastReciever and implement a listener to appB, but I have no idea how to do this...

Is it possible in a less battery-draining way?

And if the second way I suggested is the best, how can I do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible Duplicate:
[How to know when another app is begin launching?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195036/how-to-know-when-another-app-is-begin-launching/10225974)

Comment: You can't do this, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its is not possible. If it was possible, you could create an application that opens itself every time another application is launched, and this is an effect that viruses usually have.

Answer (score 0):

Create a specific register key for your application AppB.exe that load your `AppA.exe` as a debugger.

Open a Windows command prompt as Administrator and add this key:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\AppB.exe" /t REG_SZ /v "debugger" /d "AppA.exe"
```

replace `AppA.exe` & `AppB.exe` with your application

Information about this solution found
[introduction to Image File Execution Options](https://www.malwarebytes.com/blog/news/2015/12/an-introduction-to-image-file-execution-options)

Comment: *Provide context for links*: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.