# Do something (prompt) or something before an app launch android

Tags: android

Is there a way to listen or get notified when any android app is launched on the device? And do something on launch of the app on device?

Edit: Something - I meant - display an alert dialog or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event for app launch.
You can poll for current top activity though and perform action when you detect that it has changed:

```
ActivityManager sysActivitySvc = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String topActivity = sysActivitySvc.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
if(!topActivity.equals(lastTopActivity))
{
  lastTopActivity = topActivity;
  //Do your stuff here
}
```

Note that polling may impact battery usage. Don't poll for top activity more than once or twice per second.
Also, you will need to take care that your service stays active (Android likes to kill services a lot).

Comment: Thanks for the help velis, will I be able to perform my own custom action? For Eg an alert, even if I keep the service active in the background and figure out there is a change in the top activity?

Comment: Yes, a service can display a Toast or start a custom activity / app if you want.

Comment: Thanks I accept your answer because there is no other proper event for this and this is a quick fix for this. Appreciate all the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This says that it is not possible
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8293788/472336

But I think you can look for Launcher kind of app these apps can do this here is the tutorial

http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/

Comment: Thanks mate.. This is what I was afraid of. I know how to custom launch any app on device and know how to get the apps running in the background. What I was thinking was a direct way to get notified if an app is launched and then display an alert sorta there?