# Android event listener for specifics other applications

Tags: android, android-activity, listener

I want to know (with user's permissions) when few specifics apps  / activities where activated by the user, e.g. user open Gmail app.

Currently I'm doing it by ActivityManager.getRunningTasks periodically, but it’s not a good solution.
Any ideas how to do it better?

Comment: Some apps like gmail have content providers but the information they provide is determined by the app's makers. They may not provide the exact information you want.

Comment: Thanks, I know that option, but its not what I need.

Ideally, I need event: App x was opened with Activity Y

Comment: Even an event of: "some app was started" will be good, with no more detailes, and then I can check getRunningTasks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596488/android-listen-for-app-launch suggests it is not possible. It uses `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`. I guess the issue is draining the battery. I wonder if the check could only be running when the phone is active. For example when the screen is on, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478013/2832027

Comment: Thnaks TTransmit, Its not what I want but if no other option is avaliable its much better ro check only when scren is on.